# Adding new designed menu to wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, menu

I designed a menu in php file and css file..
here how its look like:

```
<div class = "menu3">

<ul>    

    <div id="menu2">

    <li><a href="#">something11</a>

        <ul>

            <li><a href="#">something</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">something</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">something</a></li>

        </ul>

    </li>

    </div>  

    <li><a href="#">something</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">something</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">something</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">something</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">something</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">something</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">something</a></li>



</ul>

</div>

<div id="header_wrapper">

</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>

<script>

$(function() {

      $('#header_wrapper').hide();

      $("#menu2").mouseenter(function() {

      $("#header_wrapper").show();

            }).mouseleave(function() {

      $("#header_wrapper").hide();

});

});



    $(function() {

      $("#header_wrapper").mouseenter(function() {

      $("#header_wrapper").show();

            }).mouseleave(function() {

      $("#header_wrapper").hide();

});

});

</script>

and the css:

    .menu3 ul ul {

display: none;

}

.menu3 ul li:hover > ul {

display: inline;

}

.menu3{

width:1388px;   

height:36px;

margin-top: -16px;

margin-left: -8px;

background-color:black;

}

.menu3 ul {

list-style: none;

position: relative;

margin-left: 250px;

line-height:35px;

}

.menu3 ul:after {

content: ""; clear: both; display: inline;

}

.menu3 ul li {

float: left;

}

.menu3 ul li:hover {

color:gray;

}



.menu3 ul li a:hover{

color:gray; 

}

.menu3 ul li a {

display: inline; padding: 0 6px;

color: white; text-decoration: none;

font-weight: bolder; font-size: 15px;

}



#menu2 li a:hover{

color:gray; 

}

#menu2 li a {

display: inline; /*padding: 0 6px;*/

color: white; text-decoration: none;

font-weight: bolder; font-size: 15px;

}

.menu3 ul ul {

background-color:black;

position: absolute;

margin-left: -66px;

line-height: 20px;

}

.menu3 ul ul li {

float: none; 

position: relative;

}

.menu3 ul li {

float: left; 

position: relative;

}

.menu3 ul ul li a {

padding: 15px 40px; 

}   

.menu3 ul ul li:hover { 

color:gray;

}   

#header_wrapper

{

background-color: black;

width: 1388px;

height: 150px;

margin-top: 0px;

float: left;

margin-left: -8px;

}
```

the problem is I dont know how to add those file to the theme,and I dont know how to put them in the code (header.php/function.php) I really dont know how to do,I just want to delete the current left-side menu,and put the new menu i created the code I created there is a way to do that? Thanks for helpers!

Comment: No one would go through your code. Clarify the question.

Comment: You have to use wp_nav_menu() . See my answer.

Comment: It would be easiest to use the native wp menu function as mentioned, and then change your `CSS` to match the markup output by the menu function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand what you need. You want to convert your html menu to wordpress menu. You have to use `wp_nav_menu()` Here is

[Tutorial](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/06/01/goodbye-headaches-hello-menus)

[Codex Tutorial](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="menu2"> <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?> </div>
```

function  wp_nav_menu will dynamically create menu  add the pages from back end and you will see them in front end  add the css to style.css